# c# youtube player для windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube

Пытаюсь сделать проигрывать музыки с youtube по ссылкам

Пробовал через компонент Shockwave, как советовали на msdn, но сейчас не поддерживается youtub-ом
Поставил компонент WebBrowser, автовоспроизведение работает
Однако есть ряд проблем, которые не знаю как решать в случае с браузером

- Присутствует реклама
- После завершения ролика, происходит переход на следующий ролик
- Нет возможности программно регулировать звук

Есть какие либо другие компоненты для воспроизведения роликов с youtube? Или может быть можно как-то решить выше перечисленные проблемы?

Comment: я могу ошибаться, просто предположу, что у youtube должно быть своё API для получения прямых ссылок на ролики, которые вы уже можете пробовать стримить каким-нибудь плеером.

Comment: Как по-вашему, за счёт чего живёт ютуб? Правильно, за счёт рекламы. Так что вы обязаны показывать её. Или должны платить за пользование ютубом. Вы можете сказать, что есть средства отключить её, есть возможности скачивать видео нахаляву. Да, есть. Но это по большей мере незаконно.